# How to make "crawl-delay" works for all "user-agent" in robots.txt or in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, robots.txt, web-crawlers

I have this line:

> Crawl-delay: 50

in the *robots.txt* file at the root of my website.

But it seems that it is not working at all. I get 400 visits from the Yandex user agent in a few minutes.

I don't want to disable the user agent but to make it to respect the delay value (50 in my situation).

How to make "crawl-delay" works for all "user-agent" in *robots.txt*?
I also read somewhere that this can be done in *.htaccess*, is this correct?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Not all search engines observe Crawl-Delay entries. Yandex has a webmaster tool that allows you to set site scanning restrictions if you don't want to block traffic outright and lose Yandex as a search engine.

Comment: Google doesn't follow Crawl-delay commands, either. You can use Google Webmaster Tools to set crawl rate.

Comment: Just wondering if I can manage the "Crawl-Delay" in .htaccess file?

Comment: @FiascoLabs: there are at least 7 user agents whose don't observe Crawl-Delay value. I don't want to register, login, and understand their tool to get this. There must be another way to make the Crawl-Delay works. I just reformulate my question to see if this can be done in htaccess file.

Comment: @ArttuRaittila : same comment as for Fiasco.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the crawl rate? Bots are not usually resource hoggers, at least the ones you can control, anyway.

Comment: @ArttuRaittila I get my server collapsed due to these bots. I can't afford to pay for a better server right now. So, I need to limit these bots.

Comment: @TomD I'm using Apache.

Comment: You can't force bots to do anything, either use their provided online tool to slow them down or block them.

Answer (score 3):

I know you previously asked to block the bots and now you just want to slow them down.

The only way to force them to slow down is not to serve them content if they are going too fast. The problem with not serving content is it will surely have negative consequences to your search engine rankings.

In case you decide to block some of the less important bots, you can block a bot's user agent using Apache's configuration like this:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent BadBot GoAway=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=GoAway
```

Just replace *BadBot* with *Yandex* or whatever the User Agent of the bot you want to block is.

When Apache sees the user agent it will pretend like there is no content available.

Keep in mind the User Agent headers are very easy to change so if Yandex changes theirs to something else, this hack won't work.